# AspNetCore 3.1 routing AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to migrate my webapp from .net core 2.1 to 3.1 and in the process changed the routing to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(default endpoint) method and removed app.UseMvc() as mentioned in the breaking changes document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#shared-framework-removed-microsoftaspnetcoreall

Post that, facing this issue.

**Details**

I have 3 controllers mentioned below in the code which are correctly versioned using the attributes

Example of V2 Controller

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}")]
```

Controllers have similar actions methods and when I try to hit any action (example: http://localhost:xxxx/v1/GetData). I get the below exception.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: 'The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

```
    Stateless1.Controllers.V3.SAPClientV3Controller.GetSap (SampleWebApp)
    Stateless1.Controllers.V2.SAPClientV2Controller.GetSap (SampleWebApp)
    Stateless1.Controllers.V1.SAPClientController.GetSap
```

PS: I have tested by removing this action method in rest of the two controllers and the call got through to the other controller irrespective of *v1* or *v2* or *v3* in the *http://localhost:xxxx/v1/GetData* URL.

The code which supports multiple api versioning is also present in the start up.

```
    services.AddApiVersioning((o) =>
    {
        o.ReportApiVersions = true;
        o.DefaultApiVersion = new AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
        o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    });
```

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` are you using?

Comment: Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 2.3.0 version in a .NET standard project which is being further used in my .NET Core 3.1 application.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue, and I found this ticket in microsoft's github issues https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/574

We need to specify the **`[ApiController]`** parameter so that the API versioning kicks in. This only started to happen when I migrated from dotnet core 2.0 to 3.1

For clarity here is what works:

```
     [ApiController]
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
        public class MyController : Controller
        {
            [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> MethodA([FromBody] int? id)
            {
              return Ok();
            }
        }
        }



[ApiController]
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
        public class MyControllerV2 : Controller
        {
            [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> MethodAV2([FromBody] int? id)
            {
              return Ok();
            }
        }
        }
```

I gave V2 names for the sake of the example, but I believe the best way to version is to use it with namespaces like V2.Home.MyController